# How to track Google Ads Search App traffic for iOS App with FireBase and BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

1. We'd like to analyze the different marketing channels separately via our existing infrastructure (FireBase to identify/attribute traffic at first, save the in-app events with parameters and export data to BigQuery for the future analyze).
2. We get the organic traffic from the App Store and everything works fine. Now we'd like to add the new channel (Paid iOs Google Ads Search traffic) and want to separate it from the organic.
3. We turned-on the Google Ads' auto-tagging setting but we don't see 'google' as source with our FireBase account (Conversions tab, first-open event). Its source was identified as '(direct)' so it mixed with the organic traffic.

Issue: we can't separate this new channel (Paid Google Ads Search for iOs app) from organic traffic in BigQuery.

All our fields 'traffic_source.source' and 'traffic_source.medium' connected with the events in BigQuery are empty.

We expect to see the events data in BigQuery with the filled-in field 'traffic_source.source' to separate the different traffic sources ('google', 'organic' etc.).

Thank you in advance.